# Excel Sort and Lookup Values Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting, vlookup, countif

I am trying to create some sort formulas on excel.

An example is shown below regarding players and their corresponding scores. I need to query the "Raw Data" and get the "Top 3" players and their scores.
[image]

I've figured out how to populate the information however I don't know how to deal when there are two points that are the same (i.e. James and Janet). I've read that I have to use `countif()` but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is probably to add a helper column where you calculate the rank of each player.

To make formulas auto-updating when you add new items, and also making them more readable I suggest to convert your raw data range to list (insert - table).

- the formula for rank:
  `=RANK.EQ([@points],[points])+COUNTIF($F$2:F2,[@points])`
- the formula to get player names and points (same formula in both columns):
  `=INDEX(Table1[[players]:[points]],MATCH($A3,Table1[rank],0),COLUMN()-1)`

[image]

Of course you can do it also without helper column but that would make your formula in column B much more complicated.

### Update

Formula without helper column:

`=OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[players]],SMALL(IF(Table2[points]=C3, ROW(Table2[points]),""), COUNTIF($C$3:C3,C3))-2,0)`

This is an array formula, you need to enter it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: I need to gather this information on a monthly basis and share with others. In order to make a less complicated spreadsheet I would like to avoid adding extra columns/info. Would you be able to help me with formulating the formula for column B without a helper column? Much appreciated!